# unwanted area filled inside the glyph

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, fonts, fill

There is a character and I would like to draw it. 
The path is correct but a filling is not.
See the picture (1. is the expected and 2. is what I get):

[image: letters, overlapping area non-filled and filled]

```
  c.beginPath();
  //draw curves
  c.closePath();
  c.fill();
```

How can I make it work?

---

With stroke(5px red):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use context.stroke() instead of context.fill()

stroke() fills the inside of a shape.

fill() draws a stroke around the outside of a shape.

Here is code and a Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/ZZD47/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; }
    canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>

<script>
    $(function(){

        var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
        var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

        // draw the inside fill of a circle
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(100, 100, 50, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
        ctx.fillStyle = 'blue';
        ctx.fill();

        // draw the outside stroke of a circle
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(250, 100, 50, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
        ctx.lineWidth = 5;
        ctx.strokeStyle = 'red';
        ctx.stroke();

    }); // end $(function(){});
</script>

</head>

<body>
  <canvas id="canvas" width=400 height=200></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: stroke() makes a stroke around the path and fill() fills it. See my updated question, where I added a stroke to the glyph. It does look like as I wanted.

Comment: I can help.  Can I see your drawing code so I can better understand your path.